# How to minimise memory usage with Entity Framework being pulled from database, then into a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, memory, model

I am pulling data using an Entity Framework, placing it in a list, and then placing that list in a `DataTable`. However it is taking up a lot of data depending on the query, I have had to take out functionality of querying the entire database because it simply crashes VS.

I need to find a way to minimize the data used, I was hoping using a data table instead of a simply HTML table would help but it hasn't, although has added some nice functionality.

I have a feeling it will require a large amount of changes in order to minimize memory usage.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class TableController : Controller
    {
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Index(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
        {
            DateTime lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);
            string selectedList = collection["list"];
            string selectedGroupType = collection["grouptype"];

            IList<SelectListItem> ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();
            IList<SelectListItem> ddl2 = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var entities = new TableEntities();

            var stock = entities.stocks.Take(0).ToList();

            if (selectedList == null && selectedGroupType == null)
            {
               stock = entities.stocks.Take(0).ToList();
            }
            else if (selectedGroupType == "grouptype=Select+GroupType" || selectedGroupType == null || selectedGroupType == "")
            {
                if (selectedList == null || selectedList == "")
                {
                     stock = entities.stocks.Take(0).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                     stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.ProductGroup ==  selectedList)).ToList();
                }
            }
            else if (selectedList == "list=Select+Company" || selectedList == null || selectedList == "")
            {
                stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.GroupType == selectedGroupType)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                stock = entities.stocks.Where(g => (g.ProductGroup == selectedList) && (g.GroupType == selectedGroupType)).ToList();
            }

            var stocktemp = entities.stocks.Select(g => g.ProductGroup).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in stocktemp)
            ddl.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item });
        ViewData["list"] = ddl;


        stocktemp = entities.stocks.Select(g => g.GroupType).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach (var item in stocktemp)
            ddl2.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item });
        ViewData["grouptype"] = ddl2;



        stocktemp.Clear();
        return View(stock);




        //Select(u => { u.StockId, u.ProductGroup , u.Category , u.GroupType , u.ItemType , u.Model , u.SerialNo , u.Status , u.DateArrived , u.CurrentLocation , u.Description , u.TerminalId }).
    }
}
```

}

And here is my View which shows how I am listing the data, although I am not sure if this is using up the memory as I believe it is the query itself.

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.stock>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <body>
    <form class="my-form" method="post" action="~/Table/Index">
        <div class="filter">
            @Html.DropDownList("list", "Select Company")
            @Html.DropDownList("grouptype", "Select GroupType")
            <br/>
            <button input type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="scrollingTable">
        <h1 id="loading" style="text-align:center;"> LOADING PLEASE WAIT...</h1>
        <table class="table-fill" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p1>StockId</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>ProductGroup</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Category</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>GroupType</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>ItemType</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Model</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Serial No</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>NR</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Status</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Description</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Date Arrived<</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Current Location</p1>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p1>Terminal ID</p1>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductGroup)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Category)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemType)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NR)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateArrived)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrentLocation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TerminalId)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#myTable").dataTable({ deferRender: true });
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#myTable').show();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons that you are having memory issues is that you are trying to load a huge amounts of data in your model into your view at one.  If that is the case, then you need to use Ajax and virtual scrolling to load the data in chunks.  There are many ways to do this, but since you mentioned DataTables, you can use the scroller extension in the DataTable.

**SOLUTION**

Here is what you need to do to accomplish this (**PLEASE NOTE** this code will need tweaking.  It will not work as is, but you can use this as an example and a way to get started).

Below are some C# helper classes that I have written to handle the **Ajax** request for jQuery **DataTable** from the controller side and also creates a **custom binding** (I have written this for **MVC6**, so you might need to tweak this for whatever version on MVC you are using):

```
public class DataTableRequest
{
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iColumns { get; set; }
    public string sColumns { get; set; }
    public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
    public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    public bool bRegex { get; set; }
    public int iSortingCols { get; set; }

    public List<DataTableColumnActions> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<DataTableSort> Sorts { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TResult> ToList<T, TResult>(IQueryable<T> Data, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector) where T : class where TResult : class
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSearch) == false)
        {
            Data = Data.Filter(sSearch);
        }

        IQueryable<TResult> result = Data.Select(selector);

        if (Sorts.Count > 0 && Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var sort in Sorts)
            {
                var column = Columns[sort.iSortCol];
                result = result.OrderBy(column.mDataProp + " " + sort.sSortDir);
            }
        }

        return result.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ToList<T>(IQueryable<T> Data) where T : class
    {
        var result = Data;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSearch) == false)
        {
            result = result.Filter(sSearch);
        }

        if (Sorts.Count > 0 && Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var sort in Sorts)
            {
                var column = Columns[sort.iSortCol];
                result = result.OrderBy(column.mDataProp + " " + sort.sSortDir);
            }
        }

        return result.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public object ToDataTableResult<T, TResult>(IQueryable<T> Data, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector) where T : class where TResult : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> inData = Data;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSearch) == false)
        {
            inData = inData.Filter(sSearch);
        }

        IQueryable<TResult> result = inData.Select(selector);

        if (Sorts.Count > 0 && Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var sort in Sorts)
            {
                var column = Columns[sort.iSortCol];
                result = result.OrderBy(column.mDataProp + " " + sort.sSortDir);
            }
        }

        return new
        {
            draw = sEcho,
            recordsTotal = Data.Count(),
            recordsFiltered = result.Count(),
            data = result.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength).AsEnumerable()
        };
    }

    public object ToDataTableResult<T>(IQueryable<T> Data) where T : class
    {
        var result = Data;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSearch) == false)
        {
            result = result.Filter(sSearch);
        }

        if (Sorts.Count > 0 && Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var sort in Sorts)
            {
                var column = Columns[sort.iSortCol];
                result = result.OrderBy(column.mDataProp + " " + sort.sSortDir);
            }
        }

        return new
        {
            draw = sEcho,
            recordsTotal = Data.Count(),
            recordsFiltered = result.Count(),
            data = result.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength).AsEnumerable()
        };
    }

}

public class DataTableColumnActions
{
    public string mDataProp { get; set; }
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    public bool bRegex { get; set; }
    public bool bSearchable { get; set; }
    public bool bSortable { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableSort
{
    public int iSortCol { get; set; }
    public string sSortDir { get; set; }
}

public class DataTableRequestProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DataTableRequest))
            return new DataTableRequestBinder();

        return null;
    }


    public class DataTableRequestBinder : Attribute, IModelBinder
    {
        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int index;
                var request = new DataTableRequest();

                request.bRegex = Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "bRegex").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                request.sSearch = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "sSearch").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                request.sEcho = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "sEcho").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                request.sColumns = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "sColumns").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                request.iColumns = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "iColumns").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                request.iDisplayLength = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "iDisplayLength").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                request.iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "iDisplayStart").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                request.iSortingCols = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "iSortingCols").Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());

                request.Sorts = new List<DataTableSort>();
                request.Columns = new List<DataTableColumnActions>();


                index = 0;
                while (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Any(k => k == "iSortCol_" + index))
                {
                    var sort = new DataTableSort();
                    sort.iSortCol = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "iSortCol_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                    sort.sSortDir = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "sSortDir_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                    request.Sorts.Add(sort);
                    index++;
                }

                index = 0;
                while (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys.Any(k => k == "mDataProp_" + index))
                {
                    var column = new DataTableColumnActions();
                    column.bRegex = Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "bRegex_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                    column.bSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "bSearchable_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                    column.bSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "bSortable_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
                    column.mDataProp = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "mDataProp_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                    column.sSearch = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.Where(i => i.Key == "sSearch_" + index).Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
                    request.Columns.Add(column);
                    index++;
                }

                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(request);
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            });
        }

    }
}

public static class IQueryableExtension
{

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByValues) where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> returnValue = null;

        string orderPair = orderByValues.Trim().Split(',')[0];
        string command = orderPair.ToUpper().Contains("DESC") ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");

        string propertyName = (orderPair.Split(' ')[0]).Trim();

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property;
        MemberExpression propertyAccess;

        if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
        {
            // support to be sorted on child fields. 
            String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
            property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);

            for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                Type t = property.PropertyType;
                if (!t.IsConstructedGenericType)
                {
                    property = t.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    property = t.GetGenericArguments().First().GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                }

                propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        }

        var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },

        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));

        returnValue = source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);

        if (orderByValues.Trim().Split(',').Count() > 1)
        {
            // remove first item
            string newSearchForWords = orderByValues.ToString().Remove(0, orderByValues.ToString().IndexOf(',') + 1);
            return source.OrderBy(newSearchForWords);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string search)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(String));
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(false);
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(CreateLike<T>(property, search));
        }
        return query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateLike<T>(PropertyInfo prop, string value)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "f");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, prop);

        // make sure string is not null
        var notNull = Expression.NotEqual(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)));

        // convert to lower case
        var toLower = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));

        // comparison on lower case
        var like = Expression.Call(toLower, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value.ToLower(), typeof(string)));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(notNull, like), parameter);
    }
}
```

You need to add the following your **global.asax**

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new DataTableRequestBinder());
```

If you are using MVC6, then add the following instead to **Startup.cs** under **ConfigureServices**

```
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                // handle loops correctly
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                                Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

                // use standard name conversion of properties
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

                // include $id property in the output
                options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                                PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
            }).AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new DataTableRequestProvider());
            });
```

Change your **Index** action to only build the **ViewData** and return an empty **view** (I omitted the ViewData part for simplicity)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

You need an action that reads the data using EF (I called it **Read**):

```
public JsonResult Read([DataTableRequestBinder]DataTableRequest request)
{
    var data = entities.stocks; // you can add your Where() and transformation here as well
    return Json(request.ToDataTableResult(data));
}
```

Then your **view** should look like  this:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100&amp;lang=en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<body>
<form class="my-form" method="post" action="~/Table/Index">
    <div class="filter">
        @Html.DropDownList("list", "Select Company")
        @Html.DropDownList("grouptype", "Select GroupType")
        <br/>
        <button input type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="scrollingTable">
    <h1 id="loading" style="text-align:center;"> LOADING PLEASE WAIT...</h1>
    <table class="table-fill" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <p1>StockId</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>ProductGroup</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Category</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>GroupType</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>ItemType</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Model</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Serial No</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>NR</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Status</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Description</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Date Arrived</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Current Location</p1>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p1>Terminal ID</p1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myTable").DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "deferRender": true,
                "scrollY": 200,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "scroller": true,
                "ajaxSource": "@Url.Action("Read", "Table")",
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "StockId" },
                    { "data": "ProductGroup" },
                    { "data": "Category" },
                    { "data": "GroupType" },
                    { "data": "ItemType" },
                    { "data": "Model" },
                    { "data": "SerialNo" },
                    { "data": "NR" },
                    { "data": "Status" },
                    { "data": "Description" },
                    { "data": "DateArrived" },
                    { "data": "CurrentLocation" },
                    { "data": "TerminalID" },
                ]
            });
    });
</script>
```

You will need **Newtonsoft.Json** for the all Json work.

Below are some references that you can take a look at:

- [DataTable Ajax](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)
- [DataTable Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/)

Comment: This looks very promising. However I have been trying to implement it, and since I am using MVC 5 there are a lot of errors. Some I wouldnt even know how to start to tackle as I do not know the MVC 5 equivalent of most of these functions.

I will however keep looking into this to see if there is something I can utilize. Thanks.

Comment: I figured that would be the case if you are not using MVC6.  This is what you will need to get lots of data to render with good perfrormance though. Just go through the errors and figure out what to change to make it compile.   Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have the same issue when I just get all data within jquery datatable for display in frontend, I think that's the html render issue, because there are a lot of html elements need to be create in a time, so the solution is you need to change to use Ajax method to get data with datatable.

Another way, I suggest you need to use the IQueryable within your backend even you use ajax call, so I think malkassem's way is good, and I also have another way to do that, I used the [dynamic linq](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) for generate the query for filter and get the result to datatable