# MVC ajax export to excel large datatable

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

This is the ajax call which is calling the controller

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "ViewData", FormMethod.Post,
     new {
         id = "myform", name = "myform"
     })) {


     <button type = "submit"> Export Raw Policy </button>
 }


 <div id = "divProcessing"> <img src = ~/assets/layouts/layout3/img/loading-spinner-blue.gif" > </p> </div>


 @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

     <script type = "text/javascript" >

         $(document)
         .ready(function() {

             // Hide the "busy" Gif at load:
             $("#divProcessing").hide();

             // Handle the form submit event, and make the Ajax request:
             $("#myform")
                 .on("submit",
                     function(event) {
                         event.preventDefault();

                         // Show the "busy" Gif:
                         $("#divProcessing").show();
                         var url = $(this).attr("action");
                         var formData = $(this).serialize();
                         $.ajax({
                             url: url,
                             type: "POST",
                             data: formData,
                             dataType: "json",
                             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                             success: function(resp) {

                                 // Hide the "busy" gif:
                                 $("#divProcessing").hide();

                                 // Do something useful with the data:
                                 $("<h3></h3>")
                                     .appendTo("#divResult");
                             }
                         })
                     });
         }); </script>
 }
```

This method is exporting the datatable into excel

```
  public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
                //sets font
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
                //sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
                                                   "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
                                                   "style='font-size:11.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
                //am getting my grid's column headers
                int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

                for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
                {
                    //write in new column
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                    //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
//write in new row
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(row[i].ToString()));
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                    }

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string abc = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            var industryData = _rawDataHlper.GetIndustryData();
            if (industryData != null)
            {
                ExportToExcel((industryData));
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I am trying to export to excel using ajax but as ajax is not downloading the file. I am struggling to find a solution. I tried to convert my datatable into Json and then pass it to the ajax. From ajax success i will get the json and export it into the excel. I wrote the below function to convert into Json

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }
        return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
```

But i am getting outofmemory exception because my datatable has more than 50,000 records. I tried to convert into the string and send the string to the ajax success but i get the outofmemory exception.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this via ajax. My whole process take 4 to 5 minutes so thats why i am using ajax to display the loader while file downloads in the background. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: use some utility parsers to pupulate the excel.

Comment: What kind of utility? I tried to search online but could not find any relevant solution

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-to-excel-using-epplus1

Comment: Thanks for the link but can i call this via ajax? Because that is i want to do i already have datatable to excel code but i cant call via ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not set all data to html in once time, this is the html performance issue, you need to use ajax for get data page by page and render them, you can try to use jquery datatable with ajax, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40601170/382576)

Comment: But for that i need to pass datatable to ajax which is i am trying to do but getting outof memory error

Comment: if you use the paging to get data by page, I think will be better, and you need to use IQueryable in backend to get data